# User input numbers into a 2 dimensional array in java

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, user-input

I'm having trouble with user input in java, hope anyone can help :)
The user declares how big the 2d array will be(number d is the side of the square array), then inputs a number "n", which tells the program how many inputs of numbers there will be, and then needs to input these numbers (eg. if n=4, the input must be sth like : 5 17 3 20. 
I have already written the same thing for a single row array

```
for(i=0;i<=n;i++) {
    arr[i]=sc.nextInt();
}
```

but am having trouble doing basically the same for the 2d array.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two nested loops and index like `arr[i][j]`

Comment: okay, so in this case, in both for loops, i and j are < than n? (i<n and j<n)?

Comment: yes, since your array is square, you can use n as the limit for both loops.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't have the ability to comment yet so I am posting this as an answer. Essentially you need to use a nested for loop as stated above. I will provide you a basic template

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i ++){
  for (int j = 0; j < width; j ++){
    if (counter < userInput){
    counter++;
    arr[i][j] = value;
      } else {
        break;        
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: so the value here is the "n" numbers from user input?

Comment: Yes it is. You should store this somewhere beforehand.

Comment: The thing with arrays is that you have to define the size before hand so if you know that you are going to have a certain number of input from the user you can just call the `sc.nextInt()` function in the loop. So it would essentially be `arr[i][j] = sc.nextInt();`

Comment: No problem. Make sure to accept answers you think are good so that people who see this later on can get the same help!

Comment: I tried doing this but don't know what went wrong... It lets me input much more than i intended to. I'll post the code in an answer bcs I can't do it here.

Comment: You can edit your original post with the new information.

Comment: Sorry I haven't seen your comment soon enough. I'll get the hang of this page soon, I hope

Comment: No problem! So I'm assuming that the first 2 numbers you know to be the number of inputs and the length of rows and columns? if that is the case I don't understand the point of knowing the number of user inputs? Are these 2 quanitites not the same?

Comment: When I say these 2 quantities I mean your height&width and your User Inputs. Because it honestly doesn't matter how many numbers your user inputs if we know how big the array is going to be. 

Regardless of the answer to that I think the main issue is that you need to check for an end condition. One way you could do this is to keep a counter and check to see something like this

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < length; i ++){
  for (int j = 0; j < width; j ++){
    arr[i][j] = value;
  }
}

Comment: I went ahead and updated my answer! In the update `counter` is your counter variable. userInput is the value you stored in `n`

Comment: I think I haven't properly described my problem... the input numbers ( like : 2 6 23 5) are (later in the program) representing the numbers between which the program will have to calculate the distance. But I'm facing that later and forgot to put it in the description. And yes, d is the number of rows AND columns because the array is a square, and the n exactly what you said.

Comment: So does the edited answer I provided help you fix the issue of just putting information into the array? I'm not going to worry about the distance stuff because as you said it is later on in the program.

Comment: just one more question - as counter, do i insert  i or j? and userInput (in the if statement) is the n in my case? thank you :)

Comment: I updated the answer again. Counter is just something you increment to see if you have inserted the maximum number of inputs allowed (this is `n` because, as you said, it was the maximum number of user inputs). And yes userInput is the `n`

Comment: well yes, but in the code, the counter goes as i or j? because in "if(counter<userInput)" if counter is "n" and userinput is "n" then it makes no sense? or I don't understand something, which is probably the case. Sorry, I'm very new to this

Comment: Haha first thanks for unaccepting my answer :P So to reiterate, counter is not `n`. Counter is an integer that starts at 0 and counts up to `n`. Once counter gets to `n` the loop will break meaning that you have added exactly `n` items to the array! This is what you want to do because you only want the `n` inputs that a user provides! 

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
            int d=sc.nextInt(); //length of rows and columns
            int n=sc.nextInt(); //user input how many  numbers



            int[][] array=new int[d][d]; //length and heigth of array

            for (int i=0;i<d;i++) {
                    for(int j=0;j<d;j++) {
                        array[i][j]=sc.nextInt();
                    }
            }   



            int distance=0;
            int c=0;
                for(int i=0;i<d;i++){
                    for(int j=0;j<d;j++){
                        array[i][j]=c;
                        c++;




                    }

                }
```

that in the end is sth else, I just wanted for the whole thing to be seen, if maybe I missed something elsewhere.

Comment: The size of each side of the square array (d) dictates the number of values that will need to be input. I'm not sure what the second part of your program is doing, but we can see that n ("how many numbers") is not being used anywhere. If you need to know how many numbers, you can multiply d by itself.

Comment: ooh okay. but so how can I make n a part of it so the program will let me input n numbers?

Comment: Well, you can count from 1 to n, taking input. However these inputs cannot be reliably stored in your square array since n and d*d could be different values. Your goal is unclear.